# Rebase or merge a branch onto another feature branch merged in master

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase, git-flow

I have a feature branching scenario that I'm working on, and I'm a little unsure which way to go as the "best solution."

```
a -- b -- c                               <-- Master
           \
            d  -- e  -- f                 <-- Branch 1 (in review)
             \            
              d -- e -- f -- g -- h       <-- Branch 2
```

I started working on `Branch 1`, finished the full implementation, and opened the pull request. However, I needed to create `Branch 2` to start the second part of the feature implementation.

```
a -- b -- c               x               <-- Master
           \             /
            d  -- e  -- f                 <-- Branch 1 (Merged in Master)
             \            
              d -- e -- f -- g -- h       <-- Branch 2
```

With that, `Branch 1` was merged by CI into the Master branch. The problem is that `Branch 2` loads all the changes from `Branch 1` and I don't know which way to merge the Master changes into my `Branch 2`.

Interactive Rebase or Merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-interractive rebase should be enough

First, make sure your local `master` is up-to-date with "`upstream`"/`master` (`upstream` being the remote referencing the target repository, where your PR was merged)

```
git switch master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

Then replay every `branch2` commit done after `branch1` start, and replay them on top of your updated `master`.

A `git merge-base branch1 branch2` should give you commit `d` of `branch1`

```
git rebase --onto master $(git merge-base branch1 branch2) branch2
```

That way, you get:

```
                            d' -- e' -- f' -- g' -- h'   <-- Branch 2
                           /
a -- b -- c               x               <-- Master
           \             /
            d  -- e  -- f                 <-- Branch 1 (Merged in Master)
```